# Reacreating Instagram "New York" filter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, adobe-lightroom

I've been looking on how to recreate the "New York" filter that's for Instagram stories.

An example of the effect that I'm after is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Wc6.jpg).

I want to create a filter that looks like this one, or something similar that looks kinda "polaroid-like".

Would be really grateful if anyone could provide instructions for getting such an effect in Lightroom or Photoshop. I'm not an expert so if you could help I'd be truly thankful

Comment: @Tetsujin the link contains 2 sets of pictures. One is original and the second is after applying the filter.

Answer (score 2):

In Photoshop, convert the layer to a Smart Object.

Apply the Camera RAW Filter, and do the following:

- Choose the Presets tab, and under Creative choose "Flat and Green"
- Under Grain, choose "Light"
- Choose the Basic tab, decrease the contrast, and the shadows, and
  increase the highlights.

Here's the result, not identical, but close.

The beauty of using the Camera RAW Filter as a Smart Filter, is that it's non-destructive. It allows you to go back into the filter to tweak it until you are happy.

[image]

This can be taken a little further. You could add a Curves adjustment layer to lift the shadows a bit to give it that slightly washed out effect.

[image]